# How does the OPTIND variable work in the shell builtin getopts

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

My shell script is quite simple, as the following:

```
  while getopts "abc:" flag; do
         echo "$flag" $OPTIND $OPTARG
  done
```

And I do some testing as the following:

```
Blank@Blank-PC:~/lab/shell/getopts_go$ sh foo.sh -abc CCC Blank
a 1
b 1
c 3 CCC

Blank@Blank-PC:~/lab/shell/getopts_go$ sh foo.sh -a -b -c CCC Blank
a 2
b 3
c 5 CCC

Blank@Blank-PC:~/lab/shell/getopts_go$ sh foo.sh -ab -c CCC Blank
a 1
b 2
c 4 CCC

Blank@Blank-PC:~/lab/shell/getopts_go$ sh foo.sh -a -bc CCC Blank
a 2
b 2
c 4 CCC
```

I cannot understand how `OPTIND` works with different command line invocation, I am confused by the output.

Can you help to figure out the mechanism of computing `OPTIND`?

Comment: excellent test script to understand OPTIND

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to `man getopts`, `OPTIND` is the index of the next argument to be processed (starting index is 1). Hence,

In `sh foo.sh -abc CCC Blank` arg1 is `-abc`, so after `a` we are still parsing arg1 when next is `b` (`a 1`). Same is true when next is `c`, we are still in arg1 (`b 1`). When we are at `c`, since `c` needs an argument (`CCC`) the `OPTIND` is `3` (arg2 is CCC and we skip it).

In `sh foo.sh -a -b -c CCC Blank`, arg1 is `a`, arg2 is `b`, arg3 is `c`, and arg4 is `CCC`. So we get `a 2, b 3, c 5`.

In `sh foo.sh -ab -c CCC Blank` args are (1:`-ab`, 2: `-c`, 3: `CCC` and 4: `Blank`). So we get: `a 1, b 2, c 4`.

In `sh foo.sh -a -bc CCC Blank` args are (1: `-a`, 2: `-bc`, 3: `CCC`, 4: `Blank`) and we get `a 2, b 2, c 4`.

Comment: Really appreciating your explanation, it troubles me a lot.
It turns out to be that I am confused by the meaning of next argument.